# Where is the implementation of the Cycles image-nodes sampling?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, image

Where is(are) the function(s) that, in the image node, transforms a point in UV space (vector that goes into the node) to a color (color of the pixel of the texture)? I can't seem to find such. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: do you mean the texture coordinate Input --> texture coordinate? and mapping node Vector --> mapping?

Comment: No, I mean the Image Texture node. ("ShaderNodeTexImage", if I remember right.)

Comment: Texture>Image Texture

Comment: UV coordinate is a X/Y coordinate for an image. There is no transformation.

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear. Let me rephrase: I am talking about the code that takes in the vector / UV point / whatever one wants to call it and returns the color of the pixel at that place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is in

```
\scripts\addons\cycles\shader\
```

You want to look into:

```
node_texture_coordinate.oso
node_image_texture.oso
```

You will find there links to appropriate .osl or .h files.

In those you will find the code and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Texture > Image Texture, then connect it to the Diffuse Shader

[image]